# Which SQL Server system database is more important: master or resource?

Tags: sql-server, database-internals

Which SQL Server system database is more important: `master` or `resource`?

If the `resource` database is damaged, can the database engine work?

Can the system work with only the `master` database?  If not, which system databases are necessary?

Comment: Why does it matter? Both are required.

Comment: This is like asking, "which part of my car is more important, the wheels or the engine?"

Comment: What is more important, front end or back end?  You need them both.

Comment: @user8365:  The sub questions seem okay but the abstract headline is probably why it was closed.

Answer (score 1):

Both the master and resource DB is important.

If the master DB becomes corrupt, you can still restart your server by creating a new master DB. You will loose your server principals and other data that are stored in the master, but at least you will be up and running. Once you recreate your logins (hopefully these were scripted) then you have access to your data.

The resource DB contains the sys schema. I am not sure if you can just copy these from another instance if there are not much changes done to these. Will have to see if there is anybody else who had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

They are both 100% required. However, mssqlsystemresource is read-only, and specific to your version/patchlevel, so it's easy to restore, in theory.

Comment: `resource` can't be backed up and restored in the traditional database sense.  It must be a file backup and restore to the directory.